# elasticsearch как перейти с 1.6 версии сервера и 2 версии elasticsearch-php до 7

Tags: elasticsearch

по данному запросу нашел много как обновить сервер и не потерять данные индекса. но в моем случае данные индекса не представляют ценности для сохранения при переходе, поскольку могут быть повторно получены. а самого важного - как перевести код запросов, включая нативного клиента для плавного, и даже не плавного перехода нигде нет. а запросы, насколько я сравнил версию 1.6 и 7 несколько разные. чтобы убедиться в этом я пробовал просто обновить сервер, но пошла куча ошибок о не правильном применении служебных параметров, исправляя которые, я получал следующую их партию. запросов поиска очень много на сайте и всегда есть шанс какой-то пропустить при переходе и узнать об этом когда будет уже совсем печально. есть ли какое руководство или последовательность действий  или какое описание как это сделать правильно без излишних затрат времени и ничего не упустить. или промежуточный клиент, который поймет старый формат запросов и будет их на лету конвертировать в новый или еще какой способ чтобы перейти с 1.6 версии сервера эластиксерч и 2 версии нативного клиента на относительно современную 7 версию? или хотя бы что-то что облегчит или ускорит этот процесс кроме сравнения запросов, выяснение необходимых изменений, поиск их в коде сайта и замена на новый формат. все попытки поиска находят либо указанное ранее обновление только сервера и индекса, ибо переход на пхп 7. прошу помочь хотя бы каким полезным советом. предполагаю, что не одного у меня такая ситуация есть или была. совместимость версий сервера и клиента такая что надо одновременно обновлять, поскольку граница совместимости идет сразу после версии 6. и даже переход сначала на промежуточные версии ничего не даст, поскольку придется тогда все делать два раза. исходя из того что уже смог найти, сравнивая требования и описания, разница только в передаче типа. но можно ли его передавать в новой и что означает его возврат в виде _doc в официальной документации не нашел. и боюсь что я что-то пропустил, поскольку не бывает так между таким количеством версий.да и как этот рункт повлияет неизвестно.
прошу не минусовать, поскольку после двухнедельных поисков этот ресурс стал последней надеждой получить полезный ответ.

Answer (score 0):

просто поверх записал новую версию. и при появлении ошибок искал как устранить. найдя иссуе в котором было устранено указанное недоразумение, порывшись по гитхабу в поиске подробностей, нашел и документы по миграции в которых все описано. https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/tree/master/docs/reference/migration.
смысла их сюда приводить нет, поскольку там много описано и постоянно обновляется и дополняется. хотя там и для самой новой версии, но уже видно какие методы удалены или изменены. а с официального сайта где есть документация https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/php-api/ сюда ссылок не нашел. 
вопрос в общем решен, но если будут полезные дополнения или ссылки на более подробные описания буду рад их почитать.